# Access VB.net DataGridView== > Error Message : "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

my VB programm works fine, then I had to add 4 new boolean fields to a table in Access2010.
I updated the datasource and the preview of the dataview works fine (Visual Studio 2019).
But unfortunately my DataGridView doesn't work anymore.
I deleted the DataGridView and created a new one with the ame name but it doesn't help.
I still the message : "No value given for one or more required parameters."

What can I do ? I checked the columns name and everything is ok ?
[image]

Comment: If you look down and to the right on this page, there is a section titled "Related" with several possible solutions for you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and believe me I spent already many hours with reading older topics.

Comment: What are the names of the new columns? Just to be sure they don't contain spaces or reserved words. Also, it might be a good idea to create the new DGV with a new name, just in case there is some remnant of the old one that didn't get cleared out.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ...I'll try with a new DGV name and also rename the columns.